# How to get the image center, strech, fill, tilt in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

How to get these effects in a J2ME project?

I need a similar effect like CSS background like we write:

```
background:#fff url(img.png) repeat-x;
```

I need this kind of thing in J2ME.  Can I do it?

Comment: What is image 'tilt'?  I am no expert on CSS, but it is not something I've heard of in that regard.

Comment: no there is no effect in css, just that was an effect.. i mean tilt like rotate in a small angle..

Answer (score 0):

I"ve never used J2ME, but I assume it supports basic Graphics functionality. Therefore you should be able to used the concepts found in the paintComponent() method of [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) to do your custom painting.

Answer (score 0):

The graphical stuff you can do out of the box in J2ME is anything found in the [`javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Graphics.html).  If you want an image repeated across the screen, you'll need to paint it repeatedly in a loop, in your `paint()` method.  You can't rotate an image through small angle; you **can** rotate through 90 degree angles using [`javax.microedition.lcdui.game.Sprite`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/game/Sprite.html).

There's no method for scaling in the API, however you could copy/paste a function like [this](http://willperone.net/Code/codescaling.php); beware, this is likely to eat up a lot of memory.